# Opinions on when to leave a country

Tags: sources-mekorot, golus-exile, anti-semitism

Would like to see some opinions and advice given by our leaders throughout galus (or before), on when it is time to leave a country, and how to decide where to go. What sort of situation or signs would warrant a Jew getting out of the country he is in, because of anti-semitism taking over, and deciding which country would be best to flee to.

This is not specifically about coming of Moshiach, or arguments for making aliyah to Israel.

Comment: "This is not specifically about coming of Moshiach, or arguments for making aliyah to Israel." Do you mean to preclude such answers or intend simply that you are also seeking a broader spectrum of answers?

Comment: @Deuteronomy I would like to focus the question. If there is an answer that involves Moshiach or Aliyah, it is fine so long as it fits as an answer to the question as stated. If it throws away the question and makes a case for moving because of Moshiach or advocates for Aliyah in general, without the context of the question then that is what I seek to avoid.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: When WW2 broke out this question was commonplace. Some Gedolim said to run and some said it will pass. In fact, the Mir Yeshiva itself, which ended up running to Shanghai, was due to the pressure of the talmidim, while the Hanhalla felt they should stay in Vilna. It is very subjective based on the exact situation of each individual.

Comment: @Chatzkel What took place leading up to and at the beginning of the Holocaust, was a completely different time and situation that was unique to then only. The confusion and poor advice of so many not to leave was because of a decree from G-d blocking the good judgement of the leaders of that generation. This is the first sign mentioned explicitly in Sefer Avkat Rochel by Rabbeinu Makir be Abba Mori.

Comment: @YaacovDeane A "...decree of God..." blocked the good judgement of the leaders of that generation? What did the Almighty decree?

Comment: @RabbiKaii I hear an underlying assumption in your question, that there should be signs to prompt a move. Jews in Egypt at the start of the 6 Day War got a knock at the door to come down down for a 5 minute meeting. Which ended up being something like a 3 year detention. On the other hand, is financial prosperity in the Diaspora a test of Hashem to see if you'd give it up to come home? Maybe it's good to read the signs, whatever they may be. What signs, though? And where? Bad ones in EY so avoid it? Bad ones in Queens?

Comment: The Chofetz chaim in nidchei yisroel perek 42 says that living in place of non Jews, or irreligious Jews, is an urgent reason to leave. He also brings the Rambam in Igeres Teiman that urged people to leave countries in which it was hard to keep Mitzvohs even if they weren’t forcing them.

Comment: @PaulWalker It’s a pleasure to write you & thank you for your service. The process of how the redemption unfolds is part of the teaching of the Torah. One of the best summaries of those teachings comes to us from the 3 volume text I mentioned above Sefer Avkat Rochel by Rabbeinu Makir of Lunel in Provence (southern France) In volume 1, first sign, he explains that the outset of the process will be characterized by a near complete disappearance of the Jewish leaders, meaning they lose their ability to lead. It is derived from a source in the Prophets. (Isaiah 59:15, Hoshea 3:4)

Comment: @YaacovDeane Thank you. If I can get a copy of that sefer in English, I'll check it out.

Comment: @PaulWalker To my knowledge, it is definitely not found in English. I’ve never heard the designation, “Nagid of Noahide Nations” before. I knew and corresponded with Vendyl Jones many times and never heard him use such a title. Is this some new designation coming out of Israel?

Comment: @YaacovDeane It is a functional designation of a non-Jewish clergy ordained by the organization Noahide Nations. A Nagid can perform weddings, lead congregations, work as a Chaplain, join professional organizations. The title comes from the Sephardic tradition. It is organizational-specific, until/unless one day Noahides unite to the point that organizations collectively agree on a title. But it's just a title for functional purposes.

Comment: @PaulWalker Thank you for the clarification. Like I was saying, my last contact on Noahide organizational efforts was from Vendyl Jones, A"H. I know he was working on something formal in Israel with Rabbi Adin Even Yisroel Steinsaltz, z"l and Rabbi Shlomo Amar, if I remember correctly. But I haven't heard anything recently.

Comment: Why would you not either make your own list of pros and cons or if that's too uncertain, flee right now?

Comment: @YaacovDeane From what I heard about him, Vendyl was a special man. I became a Noahide on a combat deployment and he died before I returned, so I never met him. But he wasn't a man that needed a title ;)

Comment: @PaulWalker Afghanistan, Iraq or Syria? I can imagine a deployment at any one of them would be life changing. You probably have an interesting backstory. Any chance you know Jim Long? He has a movie production company called Lightcatcher Studios. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_D._Long

Comment: @YaacovDeane Iraq, in Nineveh mainly. I've talked with him a few times. He's done a lot of good work. We could continue this in a chat, if you like. I don't know how to do that, though.

Answer (score 3):

This is a great but difficult question - difficult because it will vary so much by individual. It is well known that there are plenty of reasons to make alyah to Israel ([this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9652299367) is an excellent compendium of all Torah sources on the topic), however many *rabbanim* advise to wait until one can ensure an economically and spiritually stable lifestyle for their family before moving.

To take two examples from *gedolei hador* who postponed leaving

- the last Rebbe of Lubavitch never left New York, feeling that he had a role to play in the US and could not leave
- R Moshe Feinstein left Russia only after living through much persecution from the authorities and realizing there was no other alternative. When asked years later why he stayed so long (despite terrible hardships, incl. being expelled from his home and his wife not being able to use the local mikve for years because of his standards), he explained "he was the only practicing Rav remaining in his area and he saw it as an obligation to stay and guide the Jews of his and neighboring towns" (from this [biography](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422610848.html))

At the same time, everyone should be asking themselves what sort of Jewish lives their children will be having - we personally left Europe because of this and the attraction of Israel.

Comment: Thanks, however this doesn't quite answer the question, unless the answer is "if you are a Rav who is highly useful/needed, you should always stay in galus, and if not, you should always consider moving to EY if you can make it work - regardless of antisemitism"? I.e. my question is a non starter?

Comment: @RabbiKaii Based on some very recent things that have come to light, I am tempted to respond to your question. But hold back because it will not be received well here. Generally, if you, as an individual, see and recognize your surroundings to be a danger to your life, you should depart in an orderly manner. See Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh Deah 116:5, Chosen Mishpat, siman 426-427. As to where to go, the Rebbe stated explicitly that for Jews, the safest place in the world is the state of Israel. That was true 30 years ago during the Gulf War and is still true today.

Comment: @RabbiKaii Some of the best questions are those which are hardest to answer. I think it is a very difficult question to answer in general. But yes the place of Jews is in Israel and many rabbanim think every Jew should aspire to be there when it becomes possible for them, based on their individual circumstances. For some, there are good reasons to stay behind. As I wrote, your kids' lives and how you can give them the best chances should factor in big-time in your thinking (but the latter is my personal opinion).

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem?  If you feel that where you live is dangerous for your welfare, provides few opportunities for improvement, or does not allow you to pay the bills, then go somewhere else.  The Talmud says:

> If you experience bad luck in one place and don’t move to another place, you have only yourself to blame if your fortunes do not improve. [Bava Metzia 75b, and Or HaChaim on Genesis 12:1]